# How to obtain stream in proper form - System.Text.Json;

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stream, system.text.json

I am trying to convert stream into class, but I keep receiving stream as HTML (not json). Cleaning browser cache does not help. While running

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Model;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Web.Controllers.HttpControllers
{
    public class LeagueClientController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Uri _leagueRequest;
        private readonly BetDBContext _dbContext;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public LeagueClientController(IHttpClientFactory factory, BetDBContext dbContext)
        {
            _leagueRequest = new Uri("https://www.api-football.com/leagues");
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _httpClient = factory.CreateClient("BetHttpClient");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("[controller]")]
        public async Task<League> GetLeagues()
        { 
            try
            {
                var leagueResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_leagueRequest)??throw new NullReferenceException();
                if (leagueResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Stream stream = await leagueResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        var league = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<League>(stream)??throw new ArgumentNullException();
                        await _dbContext.AddAsync(league);
                        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message} - can not connect to remote source");
            }
            return new League();  
        }
    }
}
```

here is how my IHttpClientFactory is set up:

```
 builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BetHttpClient", httpClient =>
 {
     httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://v3.football.api-sports.io/");
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-apisports-key", "it is secret");
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-host", "v3.football.api-sports.io");
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
 });
```

Thank you!!!

I am expecting to obtain Stream stream as json :) and do not know how to make it, because I am receiving in browser exception: I know that html is in Stream stream, because I took `string res` as in @Tiny Wang code:

```
string res = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

[Exceptiom from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElHnW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Does this what you want?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PrivacyAsync()
{
    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7168/WeatherForecast/getjson");

    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string res = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Stream stream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        if (stream != null)
        {
            var userInfo = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<UserModel>(stream) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

And this is my API:

```
[HttpGet("getjson")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult getData() {
    var obj = new { 
        age=18,
        name="user"
    };
    return Ok(obj);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I editted question.

Comment: Hi, like you see my API will return a json, and with `ReadAsStringAsync`, I can get the json  string. The exception you got always indicating that the response from the API is not a json but an html, it always a html page with some exception messages inside it. It's better to try to call that API separately and see what the API returns.

Comment: I just realized that ""https://www.api-football.com/leagues"" is wrong line in uri string should be: "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/leagues". I searched everywhere but not this

Comment: could you pls test the api in tools like postman to see what would return when you call it?

Comment: I tested it before you asked - correct string  "v3.football.api-sports.io/leagues". is copied from postman call. You just need api key in headers.

Comment: could you pls help confirm, I mean, compare what `ReadAsStringAsync` in your code and the result you get from postman? if not, could you pls check if you missed anything in your code that made the response differ from the one get from postman?

Comment: i mean before we convert it to json, we should make sure the response is correct, if the api response from your code is correct, it shouldn't give your error. Pls correct me if I misunderstood. Or you might share the result you get from postman and the result from  `ReadAsStringAsync `